# How do I scan a folder so I can list the name of its contents in a text file? Java

Tags: java, file-io

Here is my code. So far I was able to get the directory they want to scan and the what they want to name the output file. The goal is to go to a folder and be able to scan all of that filder children names. Then I take the names and save them to a text file. I only get the names of the children of the specified folder. It is NOT supposed to open other folders and get there children. In my method listFilesForFolder(), I get a null pointer excpetion. Can someone help me figure out why i get the nullpointer exception? My code makes sense to me.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;


public class ReadWriteMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter the name of the output file... ");
        String name = reader.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please Enter the file path of the directory you would like to copy... ");
        String list = reader.nextLine();
        final File folder = new File(list);
        listFilesForFolder(folder, name);

    }

    public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder, String name) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("C:\\tempJava\\" + name + ".out");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\tempJava\\" + name + ".out");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(fw);

        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry, name);
            } else {
                output.println(fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }
        output.close();
        fw.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, mark the line which throws the exception.

Comment: If you run on Windows system, that is easily done with a simple command line that you probably can run through JAVA...

Comment: Why do you recursively call `listFileForFolder` when your intention is `It is NOT supposed to open other folders and get there children.`?

Comment: What is the input you are entering through stdin?

Comment: Also, recheck whether you're even allowed to write to C\whatever\file.out - if you're not under a root account and the IDE isn't being ran 'as administrator', this might be an issue.

Comment: You might want to refactor your code to use the [try-with-resources idiom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). That'll make it safer, cleaner and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

"*It is NOT supposed to open other folders and get there children.*"

Then don't do this `if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) { listFilesForFolder(fileEntry, name); ...`

"*In my method listFilesForFolder(), I get a null pointer excpetion.*"

If the folder you are trying to read does not exist, or you don't have permission to read it, `listFiles()` will return null. Gotta check for that.

Comment: How do I just read the names of the children of the folder I want to search?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is in this line (not your other method):

```
    final File folder = new File(list);
```

Given your code and a directory structure like this:

- C:

  - tempJava

    - myFolder

Your input should be as follows:

```
Please Enter the name of the output file... 
output
Please Enter the file path of the directory you would like to copy... 
C:\tempJava\myFolder
```

I think you may have just entered "myFolder" instead of "C:\tempJava\myFolder"?

Comment: That line is making a File object, but it's not necessarily a valid File when you go to use it.